# Why does recompiling still happen when dynamic reload is disabled in Grails?

Tags: grails

When we disable reloading, classes are still being recompiled upon changes in dev environment.

```
File /....../grails-app/controllers/test-app/org/foo/UrlMappings.groovy changed, recompiling...
```

Why does this happen?

Grails 3/4/5

Comment: "Why does this happen?" -  FYI... Some of the relevant code is at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/75fbaf8362b19864f545e94b101baa5e05e65b8f/grails-bootstrap/src/main/groovy/grails/util/Environment.java#L675-L681

Comment: The class at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/75fbaf8362b19864f545e94b101baa5e05e65b8f/grails-core/src/main/groovy/grails/boot/GrailsApp.groovy will use that method to determine whether or not to recompile.

Comment: Thank you. I saw this class still don't understand what needs to be possibly recompiled if we would disable reloading?